# How to set and echo a variable in git bash using cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, command-line

Using cmd.exe, I can run `SET "var=TEST"` and then I can run `echo %TEST` and get the result back `TEST`. How can I do this in a single command using git bash? I would think it would be `cmd.exe /c set "var=TEST" && echo %var%` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/223104/652023

Comment: This has nothing to do with `bash` (at least, not in conjunction with `cmd.exe`).

Comment: If the batch command would *also* be `set "var=TEST" && echo %var%`, then you need to escape the `&&` from being treated as the similar `bash` operator before `cmd.exe` is ever executed.

Comment: Delaying variable expansion is necessary if you want to both define/modify a variable, and use its value, within the same line or block of code. I would therefore advise that you enable it using the `/V` option with `cmd`, for example: `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /V /C "Set "var=TEST" & Echo !var!"`. To learn more abut the available options, open a Command Prompt window, type `cmd /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. I have removed all of your unnecessary tags from your question too, _(to prevent your question being propagated to uninterested parties)_.

Comment: @Compo when I enter this into git bash, I receive this error `bash: !var!: event not found`.

Comment: I have provided you with a command to run `cmd.exe` with very specific options, and an exact double-quoted argument string, which works. _(nothing whatsover should be changed, omitted, or added to what I've advised, unless you wanted to change `%SystemRoot%` to `%WinDir%` or `C:\Windows`)_. How you get that to work with `git-bash.exe`, with regards escaping the backward slashes and/or double-quotes, is a completely different issue to running a single line cmd.exe command with the specific intent of both defining and echoing a variable.

Comment: @Compo yes, that is the issue I would like to solve. Should I update my question?

Comment: No you should create another one, because your new one is related to Git BASH only. That is, you have an exact working command, and want to know how to provide it exactly as above, including all of the doublequotes, as an argument to `git-bash.exe`, or within a `git-bash.exe` interactive session. Do not let people just remove those doublequotes to make it easier for themselves, the quoting I've provided should be the default recommended template for all cmd.exe commands with arguments.